# Get the most recent date per id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does somebody know how to show only the rows that the date is the more recent by ID?

```
id date
1   2019-01-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2019-02-02
2   2018-02-02
3   2019-03-03
3   2018-03-03
```

Comment: Sorry. One column has ID like (1,1,2,2,3,3), the other column has the dates.

Comment: Are you looking for: SELECT ID,MAX(Date) FROM myTable GROUP BY ID  ??

Comment: Please add expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, MAX(date) 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

[<sup>SQLFiddle</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18f43/3)